# Search for specific Metadata type based on query on name

Tags: metadata

I want to get a list of all visual force pages whose name starts with 'MyApp_'. I am not interested in content, only in the count. Is there a metadata api for this? I can do a `'ListMetadataQuery'` with type `'ApexPage'` and then loop through all the results and filter it out. Is there any api that does the filtering itself based on name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular SOQL can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM ApexPage WHERE Name LIKE 'MyApp_%'
```

You can also use the Tooling API, which has similar syntax.